# Best practise to notify user that new version of React App is awailable?

Tags: reactjs, production

Lets say I have a website `www.example.com`, and user is using that all day without clicking browser refresh button.

When I push my changed to Prod / Master / Main, what are the ways or best practices to notify the user the there is updates ready so then they can click refresh?

Answer (score 0):

Depend on that where your app is hosted but what I did it this way show a browser native popup with message "Newest version of app is available. Do you want to refresh?" with two buttons yes and no. I think it's enough.

There's also another way, you can make an endpoint on backend with newest version of frontend and make pooling on frontend every 5 minutes. If version of frontend app is older than version on backend just refresh the page.